Linker missing using Arduino IDE
I use the Arduino IDE 1.8.5 and it seems the linker disappeared. The error messages are:
arm-none-eabi-g++: warning: {compiler.optimization_flags}: linker input file unused because linking not done\
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: {compiler.optimization_flags}: linker input file not found: No such file or directory

... bla-bla ...

*exit status 1
Erreur de compilation pour la carte Generic STM32F1 series*

I reinstall the IDE and the linker is not reinstalled, the error message remains.
Where should I look/what should I do to complete the compilation ?

key {compiler.optimization_flags} was not replaced by a value so the linker thinks it is an input file. maybe try a newer version of the IDE

Check if all necessary libraries and paths are correctly set up in the Arduino IDE. Also check if the PATH variable includes the path to the ARM toolchain and other necessary tools.
